# Coding conventions for docker-compose files?

Tags: docker-compose, linting

Is there some globally admitted coding conventions for `docker-compose` files?
Below is a sample `docker-compose.yml` from a small project we have here:

```
version: 3
networks:
  net:
    driver: 'bridge'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    networks:
    - net
    ports:
    - 3000:3000
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    networks:
    - net
  client:
    image: "app/test_clients"
    deploy:
      replicas: '3'
```

The quoting is especially inconsistent. Sometimes quotes are used around text and numerical literals. Sometimes they aren't. Sometimes single quotes are used, sometimes double quotes are used instead. The various example in the [official docker-compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) seems relatively inconsistent in that area too.

This is valid YAML. And YAML is very permissive about quoting and, as far as I know, quotes could simply be omitted in most of the cases. I know this is probably a matter of internal policy but I wonder if there are some commonly accepted "best practices" in that matter.

Comment: This answer seems well considered https://stackoverflow.com/a/22235064/329496

Comment: @simbo1905 Could you post an answer?

Comment: According to this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40158753/2777965) one could also use `docker-compose config`. I tried it and it returned `ERROR: Version in "./docker-compose.yml" is invalid - it should be a string.` and `WARNING: Some services (client) use the 'deploy' key, which will be ignored. Compose does not support 'deploy' configuration - use `docker stack deploy` to deploy to a swarm.`.

Answer (score 3):

One could use [Composerize](https://composerize.com/) to create a consistent docker-compose.yml.

There seems to be two options. Options one is to enter some docker run command, e.g. `docker run app/test_clients` on their website, which will return:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    test_clients:
        image: app/test_clients
```

Or use the [command line](https://github.com/magicmark/composerize#cli): `composerize docker run app/test_clients`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also introduce a YAML linter to your CI to ensure that a consistent docker-compose.yml format will be enforced, like [yaml-lint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml-lint). According the docs it should be possible to define a certain format. If the pipeline fails, then the developer has to apply changes in order to fix the build.